# A question about how web applications work and how server-client is implemented

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-development-server, conceptual

This is kind of a weird question I think to ask, but I have browsing about for the past some time and cannot find a clear definite answer.

I understand that a client connects to its own server and communicates with the web-server through sockets and I kind of see how that works in php (I have never used php but have used sockets before so I understand the concept). 
The issue is I'm trying to get a real view of this. 
The question is, do websites generally use sockets and contact a web-server  to fetch data or the actual html? Or is it a rare choice made in some areas?

If it is generally used, then is the "real" js usually in the server? or is it client-side (for performance sake)?

**Context:**

Let me explain a bit where I'm coming from, I'm not a web expert, but I am a computer engineering student so most concepts are easy to understand. A "real"-er view of this would be very helpful.

Now, onto why I'm asking this. I'm developing a web-app as part of a project and have done a fair bit of progress on it but everything was done on a local dev server (so basically a client?)
I've started wondering about this because I wanted to use a database for my website and since I want to connect to something, I will need to connect to a web-server first (for security sake).
My question's intent is to guide me on how and most importantly, **where**, to setup this server.

I don't think showing any code would be of help here, but assume I have my client running on localhost:1234, my database on localhost:3306, I think I should have a web-server on another port so I can establish this communication, but I want to do it in a clean and legitimate way so all of my current solutions can be ported online with little to no changes (except the obvious)

Comment: Something that runs on `localhost:1234` is a server, not a client. Are you really developing another web browser? (a web client is called a web browser, examples of web clients are: Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Microsoft Edge and Apple Safari)

Comment: I run my html on localhost:1234 because my gulpfile connects to it (the project I'm developing is from a git that was doing this, so I just used it)
I am not developing another web browser no, what I thought client meant and why I specifically used that word is something that loads the html (but that in itself is the definition of a web browser so I don't know what I'm thinking myself at this point)

Comment: That's a server. You are running gulp-webserver which is a static web server written as a gulp plugin for developers: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-webserver

Comment: What templating language are you using? pug? handlebars? just raw html files?

Comment: I see. In that case, all of my js is running client-side.
How should I run node.js on that server and connect to my database in that case? 
The fact that it was running on a static web server got my confused

Comment: Just raw html, I think at least. 3 gulp tasks are used:
build -  gulp.src(paths.html)
  .pipe(gulp.dest('build/filename'));
webserver - server = connect.server({port: 1234});
and watch that uses both of these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bunch to unpack here.

First of all, servers can be **distant** or **local**. Usually they are distant, local server are mostly used for development purposes.

Even if your server is on your local machine, it still isn't the client. The client is the part that is connecting to your server. For web development it is usually the user browser.

**Javascript** is a language that can be used server-side, with a **NodeJS** server, but more often client-side, in your user browser.

Your website, or web application, communicate with your server through various means. Most common one is the **HTTP protocol**, used to make server requests such as data request to populate your page (in case of an API server, **REST** or otherwise), or simply request the actual page to display in the browser. The HTTP protocol works by resolving URLs, and making requests to your server registered to this url using special methods such as **GET**, **POST**, **DELETE**, etc...

**Sockets** are used to create a persistent connection with your server that works both ways. It is mostly used for realtime updates, such as a live chat, as it allows you to push updates from the server instead of having the client request everything.

In most cases the **database** can be found on the same server as the one serving the website or application, as it is a lot easier to handle, and often faster without the extra networks requests to get the data. However it can be placed on another server, with it's own API to get the data (not necessarily web related)

**Ports** such as *1234* or *3306* are often used for local development, however once your move your project to a host service, this is usually replace by **urls**. And the host service will provide you with a config to access the associated database. Or if you are building your own server you might still use ports. It is heavily dependent on your server config.

Hope this clear some things up.

Comment: I understand your points on Sockets, databases and http here, and that the ports will be eventually replaced by urls, or something else depending on how the server is built, that much is clear to me, contrary to what it may seem as I have not well explained myself. 
The big confusion lies on the fact that the server running on my own machine is NOT a client. I can't seem to wrap my head around how to access and modify the server gulp built

Comment: Let's put it this way. You are the client, and your fridge is the server providing you with food. You can access the server anytime. And yet you are still in the same room/flat/house as your fridge. It's the same for your client and server, they are both in your machine but in the end they are just pieces of software.

Comment: And how to access it will vary based on what you are using to create that server. But usually you need to rebuild it again if you want to make alteration. How to access it is simulated by your network card and ports pretty much.

Comment: I like the analogy. My usual client-server interaction was always in 2 terminals, so it was clear to me there. So right now the client is my web-browser (which emulates the first terminal) and my server is the gulp process that is running on my powershell, correct? In that case, my gulp process should be the one making the requests to the database, but I don't know how I can/should do that.

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much it. If you look at your computer processes you can probably find your server living somewhere in there.
But really it would be the server itself making requests to the database. Gulp would be more like a handler and launcher for the server to compile it, run it in a thread and eventually kill it.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this means I should modify my gulp file to "expect" the requests from my client, the browser. But how should my client make these requests? What my classes have taught me to do for IP based stuff (like UDP and TCP) is to setup sockets for this communication to happen. But in a web situation, how should this happen? Imagine I want to request something from my database as an example if you may

Comment: Look at these two: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/ and https://www.sitepoint.com/using-node-mysql-javascript-client/

Comment: I feel like there's a misunderstanding about gulp. It's here to automate tasks, but it doesn't really do anything on its own. If you want to query your server from the client, you need to make http requests with javascript APIs like `Fetch` to some endpoint like `localhost:port/my-page`. Your server should listen to this endpoint `/my-page` while being deployed on `localhost:port`.

Comment: I see. About what Eriks said, I am missing the "listen" part in my gulp file.
So I would need to add that. Then I would need to make the requests by using hrefs and the responses by listening to a certain endpoint

Comment: @Morphyish Would I really need an API for this kind of interaction? I assume this is kind of a basic interaction, right? Also, do you think I can run this in my gulpfile.js? (Like as part of the watch task) Or should I completely separate it in another file and call those functions in another task?

Comment: Sadly I am not familiar enough with Gulp to be able to answer this. [gulp-webserver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-webserver) might guide you to the right path.

Comment: This is exactly what I just started to search for. Thank you! I think I'm on the right path to making this work.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Morphyish answer, in the simplest case, a web browser (the client) requests an URL from a server. The URL contains the domain name of the server and some parameters. The server responds with HTML code. The browser interprets the code and renders the webpage.

The browser and the server communicates using [HTTP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol). HTTP is stateless and closes the connection after each request.

The server can respond with static HTML, e.g. by serving a static HTML file. Or, by serving dynamic HTML. Serving dynamic HTML requires some kind of server language (e.g. nodejs, PHP, python) that essentially concatenates strings to build the HTML code. Usually, the HTML is created by filling templates with data from the database (e.g. MySQL, Postgres).
There are countless languages, frameworks, libraries that help to achieve this.

In addition to HTML, the server can also serve javascript that is interpreted in the browser and adds dynamics to the webpage. However, there could be 2 types of javascript that should not be mixed. NodeJS runs on the server and formats the server response, client javascript runs on the browser. Remember, client and server are completely isolated and can communicate only through an HTTP connection.

That said, there ways to make persistent connections between client and server with WebSockets, and add all kinds of exotic solutions. The core principle remains the same.

It does not matter if server software (e.g apache, nginx) is running on your local machine or anywhere else. The browser makes a request to an address, the DNS and network stack figures out how to reach the server and makes it work.

Comment: So it really works the same way as a client-server communication between 2 terminals, or on LAN, with some added layers.
Thanks for clearing stuff up. I think I get the gist of how this works, what I would need to figure out now is implementing this into my own solution. The fact that my starting project was using gulp really got me confused.

Comment: Gulp is usually used as an automation tool. Do not overcomplicate. Have NodeJS server running serving static responses that you can see in the browser. Then add some code that fetches data from a database. See links in my earlier comment

Comment: I see, I will see to integrating this in my automation process then, thank you!